# i686-w64-mingw32 gives error on ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, 12.04

I have some package in Ubuntu 12.04 .. which is getting compiled with the help of `i586-mingw32msvc`.
My task is to compile same package on Ubuntu 16.04 which does not have `i586-mingw32msvc` ( as per my finding )  and having  `i686-w64-mingw32`  for 32 bit system .

I am getting compilation error (shown in below ) in base `i686-w64-mingw32` itself in header file . Please suggest if there is any tool chain to compile `i686-w64-mingw32` in ubuntu16 .

Is there any way to compile `i686-w64-mingw32` under ubuntu 16.04

```
usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:147:25: error: expected declaration specifiers before 窶論_declspec窶・ #define DECLSPEC_IMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
                         ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/apisetcconv.h:43:20: note: in expansion of macro 窶魯ECLSPEC_IMPORT窶・ #define WINBASEAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT
                    ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/sysinfoapi.h:37:3: note: in expansion of macro 窶聾INBASEAPI窶・   WINBASEAPI VOID WINAPI GetSystemTime (LPSYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);
   ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:147:25: error: expected declaration specifiers before 窶論_declspec窶・ #define DECLSPEC_IMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
                         ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/apisetcconv.h:43:20: note: in expansion of macro 窶魯ECLSPEC_IMPORT窶・ #define WINBASEAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT


usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:527:32: error: declaration for parameter 窶廊PFXPT2DOT30窶・but no such parameter
   typedef __LONG32 FXPT2DOT30,*LPFXPT2DOT30;
                                ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:527:20: error: declaration for parameter 窶炉XPT2DOT30窶・but no such parameter
   typedef __LONG32 FXPT2DOT30,*LPFXPT2DOT30;
                    ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:526:33: error: declaration for parameter 窶廊PFXPT16DOT16窶・but no such parameter
   typedef __LONG32 FXPT16DOT16,*LPFXPT16DOT16;
```

Comment: I think you have to try `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32` command from `gcc-mingw-w64-i686` package on 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Hi @N0rbert  thanks for suggestion can you please more elaborate. do I  need to install gcc and compile ?  I used sudo apt install mingw-w64  for installation .

Comment: I mean - install the `gcc-mingw-w64-i686` package and then try to compile your software using its GCC (the `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32` command).

Comment: Thanks So much @N0rbert  looks like it helped me .

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually install packages from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onto your current 16.04 LTS system with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32-binutils/mingw32-binutils_2.20-0.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32-runtime/mingw32-runtime_3.15.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32/mingw32_4.2.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./mingw32*.deb
```

to get all `i586-mingw32msvc*` prefixed commands installed.

Comment: Thanks N0bert  above comment  your above mentioned comments helped me .I am getting some other issue will keep posted on different thread if not solved .

Comment: Great, so you can accept the answer here, I will follow new thread.

Comment: Yes answer is useful . Not getting any ui to accept it